# Looping through the file,searching nan's

Tags: linux, bash

I have file with 12000 lines,some of them are nan's
I have written bash,to search for these nan's

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'

cat file0.txt | while read line 
do
if ! [[ $yournumber =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
fi
done
```

But only this appears on the screen

```
error: Not a number
```

What's wrong with my bash?

Comment: Where does `$yournumber` get set?

Comment: (A tip: http://www.shellcheck.net and `set -eux` are your best friends when writing shell scripts.)

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for reading files - `cat | while read` is often *not* what you want (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using exit statement, that means this script will immediately exit after printing FIRST `error: Not a number` . So what is the problem with the script?

People may do `if grep '^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$' file0.txt then` instead.

Comment: Or `grep -v`, to mimic the question.